# How to debug when CakePHP Model::save() doesn't attempt an INSERT

Tags: cakephp

I am having a bear of a time saving the simplest record from a model called ItemView:

```
if($this->save($this->data)) {
  echo 'worked';
} else {
  echo 'failed';
}
```

Where $this->data is:

```
Array
(
    [ItemView] => Array
        (
            [list_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 1
        )
)
```

And my table is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `item_views` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `list_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `user_ip` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Looking at the query dump in debug mode, Cake isn't even attempting an INSERT, so I have no idea how to debug.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this will be helpful and save time http://teknoid.wordpress.com/2008/06/09/15-essential-cakephp-tips/

Comment: By the way you should be using InnoDB as your database engine also.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Wow, two miserable hours of my life wasted.

Remember that your `beforeSave()` must return `true`!

Comment: I spent 8 hours duplicating this and finding the same thing. Wish I had searched SO earlier!

Comment: ahhh, thanks for saving my life. this problem costs me 2 hours

Answer (score 24):

To debug Model->save() check the validation errors and the last sql query

```
$this->Model->save($data);

debug($this->Model->validationErrors); //show validationErrors

debug($this->Model->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false)); //show last sql query
```

Answer (score 10):

In cakephp 3.x, you can debug during insert/update

```
if ($this->TableName->save($entity)) {
      // success 
} else {
// if not save, will show errors 
  debug($entity->errors());

}
```

Comment: The newer version seem to use: $entity->getErrors()

Answer (score 8):

What always gets me is that if I modify the actual table (usually by adding attributes to it), then you must flush your cache. Usually just deleting everything inside the following two folders does the trick for me:

```
tmp > cache > models 
tmp > cache > persistent
```

Comment: This was super helpful!! after 2 hours of derping around I win... Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of controller you are using?

Mismatching the name of controller and model also cause some errors. If you are using Posts controller then the `Post` model should be used. If you are using `Post` model inside other controller; say `BlogsController` then the `Post` model should be loaded like following:

```
    <?php
    class BlogsController extends AppController
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $this->loadModel("Post");    
            //Here I'm loading other model inside blogs controller
            if($this->request->is('post'))
            {
                $this->Post->save($this->request->data);
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be, Validations returns false.. You can check like

```
$this->Model->save($this->data, false);
```

Put false and check whether now data inserts, if it is then it is validation error

Comment: What? How about just checking Model->validationErrors instead on fail?

Answer (score 1):

may be something like this

```
$this->Model->set($this->data);

$errors = $this->Model->validate();// or perhaps validationError(), please confirm

if(!$errors) {
   $this->Model->save();
}else{
   //show errors
   pr($errors);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. I wasted 2 hours of my life.

Solution:
I forget to this:

```
array('post', 'put')
```