# Save is not working as expected in cakephp 1.2

Tags: php, cakephp

using cakePhp for an existing product they have old version 1.2.
I just started using CakePhp. 
I tried to save some data to the table.
here is my code.

```
function add(){

        //echo $id;
        pr($this->data);
        if(!empty($this->data)){
            $this->User->create();
            if($this->User->save($this->data)){
                debug($this->User->validationErrors);
                exit();
                $this->Session->setFlash("Data saved man");
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index',2));
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is debug data.

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => hello
            [last_name] => man
            [email] => lrer@drei.cm
            [password] => 123
            [created_at] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 01
                    [day] => 17
                    [year] => 2014
                    [hour] => 08
                    [min] => 56
                    [meridian] => am
                )

            [modified_at] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 01
                    [day] => 17
                    [year] => 2014
                    [hour] => 08
                    [min] => 56
                    [meridian] => am
                )

        )

)
app\controllers\users_controller.php (line 36)
Array
(
)

(default) 0 query took ms
Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms).
```

I have no clue why data is not saving to database. I need to get it work for version 1.2. thanks

Comment: I accept this is due to carelessness, but I left this question here as I see many of my friends repeating the same error as mine.

Comment: This may be helpful in this type of scenario . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566508/how-to-debug-when-cakephp-modelsave-doesnt-attempt-an-insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `user` key should have capital U as `User`. Check your view code to make sure that the model passed to `$form->create('User')` not `'user'`

Comment: You are right man. oh! my bad. How can forget that array keys are case sensitive. Thanks.